# Component property derived from a custom class

Tags: delphi, class, components

I create my own class and I want to use it in my new component but I am getting an error...
The code is the following:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    Name: string;
    Number: double;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyClass: TMyClass;
  public
    procedure SetMyClass(aName: string; aNumber: double);
  published
    property MyClass: TMyClass write SetMyClass;
  end;

procedure SetMyClass(aName: string; aNumber: double);
begin
  FMyClass.Name:= aName;
  FMyClass.Number:= aNumber;
end;
```

it appears that the property has incompatible types, I don't know why.

Does anybody has a clue about that and how can I solve this problem.
Having a FName and FNumber as fields in TMyComponent is not an option, my code is more complex and this is a simple example to explain my goal.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things that I can see wrong with your code at present are:

1. The property setter must receive a single parameter of the same type as the property, namely `TMyClass`.
2. The property setter must be a member of the class, but you've implemented it as a standalone procedure.
3. A published property needs to have a getter.

So the code would become:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    Name: string;
    Number: double;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyClass: TMyClass;
    procedure SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
  published
    property MyClass: TMyClass read FMyClass write SetMyClass;
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
begin
  FMyClass.Name:= Value.Name;
  FMyClass.Number:= Value.Number;
end;
```

This code does not instantiate `FMyClass`. I'm guessing that the code that does instantiate `FMyClass` is part of the larger component code that has been excised for the sake of this question. But obviously you do need to instantiate `FMyClass`.

An alternative to instantiating `FMyClass` is to turn `TMyClass` into a record. Whether or not that would suit your needs I cannot tell.

---

It looks like you are having some problems instantiating this object. Do it like this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    Name: string;
    Number: double;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyClass: TMyClass;
    procedure SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property MyClass: TMyClass read FMyClass write SetMyClass;
  end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyClass:= TMyClass.Create;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FMyClass.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
begin
  FMyClass.Name:= Value.Name;
  FMyClass.Number:= Value.Number;
end;
```

One final comment. Using `MyClass` for an object is a bad name. Use class for the type, and object for the instance. So, your property should be `MyObject` and the member field should be `FMyObject` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I see now where my mistake was. However I still get a problem, I can compile and install it now, but when I drop the component on the form, I got an "Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000". And the component doesn't appear on the form. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Remember that you did not show us your code. You only showed a cut down version of the code. The code in my answer is still cut down, following your lead. And note my discussion of the fact that `FMyClass` is not instantiated. We can only comment on the code that you showed us. Did you ever instantiate `FMyClass`?

Comment: I posted here an example of my own code, in this simple example I also get the same error

Comment: Your code must call inherited; as the first line of the constructor.

Comment: I am using your code and it also does not work. It works only if the the property my class is not published...

Comment: I guess the property needs a getter too.

Comment: Only one last question. Why SetMyClass needs to be declared in the private section?

Comment: It doesn't need to be. It just hides it from consumers of the class. They are meant to use the property.

Comment: Don't forget that `TMyClass` must also be derived from `TPersistent` in order to be DFM streamable since it is declared as `published`.

Comment: Can you help me using this TPersistent? As you said if I don't use that I can not get the values of the properties settled at design time... I tried: TMyClass=class(TPersistent) but it doesn't work at all, what else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    Name: string;
    Number: double;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyClass: TMyClass;
  public
    procedure SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
  published
    property MyClass: TMyClass write SetMyClass;
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyClass(Value);
begin
  FMyClass := Value;
end;
```

Comment: I believe the Felipe's code is incomplete and I have supposed what not exist. In addition not exist GET function and therefore not exist risk reading.

Comment: You've accepted this, but it's very unlikely that this is your answer. You'll be leaking objects left right and centre. I tried to persuade David to discuss that issue, but so far he has not obliged. It's also odd that your code in the question treats `MyClass` as a value, but that you accept an answer that without explanation changes the semantics to `reference`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unit MyComponentTest2;

interface

uses SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, Messages, Dialogs;

type
  TMyClass = class
    Name: string;
    Number: double;
  end;

  TMyComponentTest2 = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyClass: TMyClass;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
  published
    property MyClass: TMyClass read FMyClass write SetMyClass;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TMyComponentTest2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
  FMyClass:= TMyClass.Create;
end;

destructor TMyComponentTest2.Destroy;
begin
  Inherited;
  FMyClass.Free;
end;

procedure TMyComponentTest2.SetMyClass(Value: TMyClass);
begin
  FMyClass.Name:= Value.Name;
  FMyClass.Number:= Value.Number;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMyComponentTest2]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: What is this meant to be? This is just what I already said. And you still leak because there's no destructor. Do you need help with constructors and destructors?

Comment: other problem is you are missing a call to inherited constructor

Comment: you said that I should instantiate FMyClass, so it is there:
FMyClass:= TMyClass.Create; if is not this I don't know how to instantiate right this class

Comment: That bit is fine. But the missing destructor and missing inherited in the create are still hurting you.

Comment: yeah, I already corrected that, I forgot because I wrote this code fast to show you, but even though there is still memory leaking...

Comment: I also figured out one thing, if I set the FMyClass to be public and not published the code works... but I would like to have it in the Object Inspector...

Comment: A detail. setMyClass procedure should be private section

Comment: I did it, but still nothing, I only get to work if FMyClass is public

Comment: Usually a property is defined with get and set or get. Rarely with only one set procedure. Normalmente una propiedad se define con set y get o con get. Raramente con unicamente un procedimiento set ;-)

Comment: That is it, I added a read in the property and it works. THANKS A LOT. I uploaded the working code

Comment: Ahhh!. Now this is most normal ;-)